# Can we have multiple faces-config.xml files in our JSF application?

Tags: jsf, faces-config

I am working on a project which has grown bigger and lots of works still remains.
The thing is, the entries in my `faces-config.xml` has already spanned some 600 lines, and I fear it will double up in coming months.

I was thinking if there might be some way so that I can have more than one `faces-config.xml` file in project, then I could have configured them according to my modules, which will ease to work with many folders.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, you can

For example you can configure your *web.xml* as follows and divide it.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>
        WEB-INF/module1/user-manage-beans.xml,
        WEB-INF/module1/user-navigation-rule.xml,
        WEB-INF/module2/patient-manage-beans.xml,
        WEB-INF/module2/patient-navigation-rule.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml,
        /WEB-INF/configs/customer-config.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Comment: Nope. This code won't work. The context parameter name is wrong. It's the misdocumented one. And, you don't need to redefine the original `faces-config.xml`.